# UIWebView не открывает домены на кириллице

Tags: xcode, ios, objective-c

Пытаюсь открыть домен в зоне рф. А получаю ошибку

> didFailLoadWithError - Error
> Domain=WebKitErrorDomain Code=101 "The
> operation couldn’t be completed.
> (WebKitErrorDomain error 101.)"

Чего не хватает?

```
_webView = [[UIWebView alloc] init];
    _webViewTitle.title = _url;
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:_url]];
[_webView loadRequest:request];
```

Comment: "Нужно больше золота"© Orc from Warcraft. 
1. что за урл?
2. что в делегатах приходит?
3. на симуляторе или устройстве?
4. может нет доступа к сети интернет?

Comment: Умные китайцы давно написали решение https://github.com/Wevah/Punycode-Cocoa